# Can't install gtk-3-dev: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, gtk3

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 and have been trying to install libgtk-3-dev, but getting the following error:

```
~/Downloads/Software $ sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libepoxy-dev (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

I tried fixing with all the following:

- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` (all good, no errors in output)
- `sudo apt update --fix-missing` (all good, no errors in output)
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (empty output, no errors)
- `sudo aptitude install libgtk-3-dev` (no errors, but package is not installed)
- Synaptic through UI (gives me the same error)

Nothing works. Any ideas what should I try next?